# unspecified error when binding to source control in VS2013

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2013

just upgraded a VS2010 project to VS2013.  Project was already under source control in TFS.
Now everytime i open the solution, i receive a box that states something like "Project is already under source control but is not currently configured to use integrated source control.  Would you like to configure now? Yes or no"

So if i click on 'Yes' it brings up the 'Change source Control' which shows it not connected to any server or anything.  I am unable to click on the 'Connect' checkboxes and if I click 'bind' it will throw an 'unspecified error'

Help please.  I need to ensure i can check in/out changes so that other developers are able to get the latest.

Comment: What did you do to "upgrade" the project to vs2013?

Comment: Actually it was "upgraded" by another developer.  Not exactly sure what he did.  The project no longer will open in VS2010, as it says it is incompatible.  I can work on the project without binding it, however there does not appear any way of checking in any changes i make if i do that.  Also the other developer is on a totally different changeset on some of the files.  I am thinking that TFS might not be setup properly....

Answer (score 0):

After investigate a few about your problem, i think you have two options:

- Make a new repository with your project using vs2013.
- Use your project (that is on TFS) with vs2010.